# Redeploying Custom Control flow component SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have developed a custom control flow task component, just want to check if there is any specific process or way in which if we redeploy the second/later versions of the component then we need not reset toolbox and add the component manually to the Toolbox? As of now if I make any changes to the custom component and redeploy, I have to reset toolbox and readd the component in BIDS.Which is causing problems.

Thanks in advance

Sai

Answer (score 0):

Fix the assembly version, so it does not change with every deployment.

I.e. if your AssemblyInfo.cs specifies assembly version 1.0.*, make it e.g. 1.1.0.0, and don't change it, except between major incompatible releases.